# Trying to use PATCH method works with AJAX but not with a regular html form

Tags: php, jquery, altorouter

I'm currently trying out http://altorouter.com/ and it's working well for me so far, except for this one issue I'm having

My route is set up like this:

```
$router->map( 'PATCH', '/admin/pages', 'pageController@update');
```

If I use the following jquery, the route works perfectly:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PATCH",
    url: "/admin/pages",
    data: {page_items:page_items, page_name: 'test_page'},
    success: function(returned_data)
    {
        console.log(returned_data);
    }
});
```

However, no matter what I put in my HTML I can't get a regular form to submit in a way it accepts as PATCH:

```
<form action="/admin/pages" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_function" value="edit_theme">
    <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PATCH">
    <button type="submit">Save Page</button>
</button>
```

I've tried "_METHOD", "_method", "method" etc. None of them work.

I've also tried

```
method="PATCH"
```

but that only causes it to do a GET.

When I echo the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] on the target page I get "PATCH" for the ajax, but just "POST" for the form. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot.

As you'll see in the [W3 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms)

The only valid methods for HTML based forms are "GET" and "POST".

However you can work around this if you wish, on the server side instead. Theres a great article about how Laravel does it here: [Theres no Put/Patch Delete Methods](http://laraveldaily.com/theres-no-putpatchdelete-method-or-how-to-build-a-laravel-form-manually/)

A quick snippet of code from that article:

```
<form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
</form>

<form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">  
</form>
```

> If you are not using Laravel and want to build a form manually, you cannot use PUT/PATCH – there’s just no such methods supported by forms in browsers – it’s only GET and POST. So how does Laravel make it work with {{ Form::create([‘method’ => ‘PUT’]) }}?
>   Actually, under the hood the generated HTML looks like this:
>
> That’s right, Laravel constructs a hidden field with name _method and
>   then checks it upon form submittion, routing it to the correct
>   Controller method.
>
> So if for any reason you would need to build the FORM tag yourself,
>   don’t put  (same applied to patch and delete) – it
>   just won’t work. Instead add hidden fields, if necessary.

So back to your issue, *Altorouter*. It appears their documentation is rather lacing the best guide I can find for you is here https://recalll.co/app/?q=rest%20-%20PHP%20detecting%20request%20type%20(GET%2C%20POST%2C%20PUT%20or%20DELETE)%20-%20Stack%20Overflow it might be worth your while finding a better router, as Alto doesn't seem to have been updated in around 3 years.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found a solution that works for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a working solution after digging around in the code. Altorouter's match method actually accepts a method parameter, which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Where I used to have

```
$match = $router->match();
```

I now have:

```
if(isset($_POST['_method']))
{
    $match = $router->match(null, $_POST['_method']);
}
else
{
    $match = $router->match();
}
```